# Android Glance Widget - Any way to tint a Shape drawable with borderRadius?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, glance-appwidget, glance

Using Glance-beta01

CornerRadius modifier cannot be used on Android 12-, we have to use a drawable with a shape like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFF" />

    <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius_outside" />
</shape>
```

Ok now, what if I want to dynamically change the color ? It seems not possible while keeping a "responsive" UI (saw a solution by converting to a bitmap but not responsive)

Thanks